# Fetch photos from iOS photo library by its location

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

Is it possible to retreive photos from photo library using their location? I know for sure location information exists in photo's metadata (fact: "Places" folder shows where pictures were taken).
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fetch photos by location as the documentations says, sadly. The only way is to fetch all `PHAsset`, or fetch using a time interval if you can. Then you can enumerate your results and access the `PHAsset.location` property to filter the photos.